# How to increase the file size limit in WCF console application

Tags: c#, wcf

I've having a very simple WCF service (a console application  for file upload). I keep getting error (400) bad request. It works when I upload small files (4kb) but failing for 700kb.

From the readings I've done from stack overflow and other, I'll have to increase the MaxReceivedMessageSize. This was implemented using a custom class and overriding the OnOpening method but it still didn't work.

I'm testing with a console application using the webclient
    `outputBytes = webClient.UploadData(baseUrl + "/uploads/2." + filenameOnly,     File.ReadAllBytes(filename));`

Also, I'm using the WebServiceHost as in
    `var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:8000");

        var svc = new WebServiceHost(typeof (UploadService), uri);`

How do I solve this issue? 
PS: Application does not have a config file so I'll looking at how to set this in code. If not and a config  file is needed, then what should be the content.

Notes:
I found this link [Bad Request Error 400 - WCF Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607437/bad-request-error-400-wcf-client) where it was explained that those properties are only valid for soap based services. He suggested updating the web.config. Since this is a console application, I'm wondering how this can be done'

regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the maximumreceivedmessage programatically like this:

```
 var binding = new wsHttpBinding(); // or whatever binding you are using
 binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue; 
 var wcfClient = new WCFServiceTestClient(binding, strServiceURL);
```

Hopefully this will be enough to solve your problem, but you might also want to consider chopping up the file into bits (batching) before sending it to the server. Sending very large chunks of data can incurr a huge memory penalty as the client has to serialize the entire thing up front before sending it to the server (and then the same to deserialize it on the server side).

**Edit:** Based on your additional comment (below), the code on the application hosting the service might look something like this:

```
        WebServiceHost webServiceHost = new WebServiceHost(typeof(UploadService), uri);
        WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding();
        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue;
        webServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IUploadService), binding, "WebServiceHost");
        webServiceHost.Open();
```

Comment: Hi, I'm creating a restful wcf web service. Below is the code 
        `private static ServiceHost CreateWebServiceHost()
        {
            var uri = new Uri(SysValues.baseUrl);
            var svc = new WebServiceHost(typeof (UploadService), uri);
            return svc;
        }`
         That is all the code there is. Where do I set this? I'm not explicitly creating a binding so I dont know where the property is found.

Comment: I updated my answer based on the fact you are using WebServiceHost, to show how to add the service endpoint. Let me know if you need any more information :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a [look at the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.maxreceivedmessagesize.aspx)?

It covers both code and configuration.

Comment: Hi, I've seen that link but I dont know how it to apply to mine since I do not explicitly create the binding.

Comment: You are still using a binding even if you did not configure one. To adjust the setting you need to configure the binding by using a standard binding such as the httpBinding and setting the properties as required. If you are hosting in IIS/WAS the best way to configure the binding is by specifying it in the web.config

Comment: I'm using a console application. What code do I write to do this. I'm creating an instance of the webservicehost for this.  `var svc = new WebServiceHost(typeof (UploadService), uri)`

Comment: Yeah. Apparently it was possible. I didn't see that second link. Thanks.